# Retrieving attributes value from soap response

Tags: android, soap, attributes, ksoap2

I am using ksoap for using webservice in my application. The output response contains attributes also. The response will be something like this;

```
<Response xmlns="namespace">
  <Result Id="number" Name="value"></Result>
</Response>
```

How can I retrieve value of Id from this? I tried with getAttribute() method but it did not work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution!
I referred this: http://www.simpligility.com/2010/05/attribute-support-for-ksoap2-on-android/

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

[you need to learn Sax parser. what is Sax parser click here.with example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser)

Comment: I know about SAX Parser but I need to do it using methods of soap not parser methods.

Comment: I do not want to use SAX parser I want to use the methods of ksoap like I use getProperty() to get value of any tag.

Comment: http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/03/03/how-to-consume-web-services-from-android-applications-using-ksoap2/

Comment: I guess you are not getting my question.